# Display s supported resolution is above the maximum supported one of the card. How do I decrease console resolution of the plain Linux console?

Tags: linux, fedora, resolution, vga, fedora-33

Max resolution of [the vga card is 1440x900x32](http://www.aspeedtech.com/server_ast2500/). So when the Linux kernel detects the resolution on boot of 1680x1050x32 supported by the screen through edid and set it to it, the image is croped to 1440x900
[image]

Is there a way to decrease the resolution back to 1440x900 so I can see all the results of the commands I m typing without characters truncation?

Comment: Does [boot parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/x86/boot.html?highlight=boot%20parameters#special-command-line-options) `vga=ask` present an option that works?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it s unrelated. Whatever the boot resolution set by grub2, the kernel will set the resolution to the one probed  from the edid.  And if I m using `nomodeset`, the computer freeze once wayland automatically start.

Comment: Perhaps you need a [corrected EDID data set](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/edid.html).

Comment: @rickhg12hs and without recompiling the kernel? Because do you imagine modifying source files without seeing what I m typing?

Comment: It's always a challenge developing kernel related software on the target system.  Perhaps setting [`gfxpayload`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/gfxpayload.html) will be sufficient?  There are plenty of tutorials online to learn how to set it.

Comment: Again, I can set any resolution on boot. The problem is kms overriding it later.

Comment: If you pass `modeset=0` option to your video driver, will it not switch after boot?

Comment: @rickhg12hs then the computer hang as soon as Wayland starts.

Comment: Which video driver is being used?

Comment: @rickhg12hs I don t know how to check the driver being used for the console.